# How to calculate ratios by group based on a specific row in a datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I have trade data with the following structure :

```
MWE <-data.table(
  Exporter=rep(c("France","Germany","United States","World"),each=4),
  Importer=rep(c("France","Germany","United States","World"),4),
  Value=c(0,20,30,50,
          30,0,40,70,
          80,80,0,160,
          110,100,70,280)
)

MWE

> MWE
         Exporter      Importer Value
 1:        France        France     0
 2:        France       Germany    20
 3:        France United States    30
 4:        France         World    50
 5:       Germany        France    30
 6:       Germany       Germany     0
 7:       Germany United States    40
 8:       Germany         World    70
 9: United States        France    80
10: United States       Germany    80
11: United States United States     0
12: United States         World   160
13:         World        France   110
14:         World       Germany   100
15:         World United States    70
16:         World         World   280
```

I want to create a new variable that is the share of each country among the importers from one country. I cannont easily do things using `sum` or `N` as I have various group of countries in my real data (`World` in my example).

So basically I want a new variable that is, `by Exporter, percent = value/value(World)` . How can I do that ?

```
 Desired_Output
         Exporter      Importer Value   Percent
 1:        France        France     0 0.0000000
 2:        France       Germany    20 0.4000000
 3:        France United States    30 0.6000000
 4:        France         World    50 1.0000000
 5:       Germany        France    30 0.4285714
 6:       Germany       Germany     0 0.0000000
 7:       Germany United States    40 0.5714286
 8:       Germany         World    70 1.0000000
 9: United States        France    80 0.5000000
10: United States       Germany    80 0.5000000
11: United States United States     0 0.0000000
12: United States         World   160 1.0000000
13:         World        France   110 0.3928571
14:         World       Germany   100 0.3571429
15:         World United States    70 0.2500000
16:         World         World   280 1.0000000
```

Comment: Does this work for your real data: `MWE[, share := Value / Value[Importer == "World"], by=Exporter]` ?

Comment: After a few checks it seems so, did not know this syntak !

Answer (score 1):

How about this with `dplyr`? Because you have world included, you need to double the percent. This will only work if world is included consistently. Otherwise, you can use an if_else statement.

```
MWE %>% group_by(Exporter) %>%
  mutate(2*Value/sum(Value))
```

Comment: IRL I have almost all countries, and several groups (e.g. continents, free exchange zones and so on) so this does not seem viable